# How to delete multiple documents in elasticsearch?

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I want to delete many documents from elasticsearch that don't exist anymore on my database.

I know that to delete multiple documents (with ids 1,2,3 for example) we use :

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/doc/ids=1,2,3
```

But I want to keep only those ids and delete the rest, it something like the following instruction in SQL.

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id_column NOT IN (1,2,3);
```

Is there an equivalent of NOT IN in this case for elasticsearch?

Comment: this might be useful https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Answer (score 7):

It may be little dangerous but you can use `delete by query`. [delete by query api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html)

The query will be something like this:

`query : {bool : { must_not : {ids : values : [1,2,3,... ]}}}`